# Specific column's data search using apache solr

Tags: java, mysql, solr

am using apache Solr for searching my database..!!

Suppose i have indexed 3 columns from one of my table..!!..I just want that only those columns that contains my query term are returned in response..!!..is that possible..??

For example :

I have a table cars with columns : questions, answer, type ..!!
Now i make a query , something like :

```
localhost:8983/solr/select?q=tomato&wt=json
```

Now some in some rows only name may contain the word "tomato"
So, In return, i want only name (along with some other fixed fields like ID) ..

Similarly, If answer contains this word, then only answer should be returned..and not other columns..!!

How can i acheive this..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are searching the term "tomato" in a field called question then your query will be as follows

```
localhost:8983/solr/select?q=quesion:tomato&wt=json
```

And if you want to return the field question alone then your query will be

```
 localhost:8983/solr/select?q=quesion:tomato&wt=json&fl=question
```

You can mention the list of fields that you want to return in **fl** with comma separated values as below

```
 localhost:8983/solr/select?q=quesion:tomato&wt=json&fl=question,id
```

Comment: but i got unrelated questions those does not contain "tomato" keywords

Comment: Is their any changes in solrconfig.xml/schema.xml file??

Comment: Can you post your sample document and the output you are getting

Comment: its not possible here...can u plz give me ur email id